# Updating posts not working

Tags: wp-update-post

Lets say I want to change a posts comment count to 50 everytime the post is viewed.

I have this simple code in *functions.php*:

```
function update_shares() {

  $my_post = array();
  $my_post['ID'] = get_the_ID();
  $my_post['comment_count'] = 50;
  $my_post['shares'] = 50;

  if (wp_update_post($my_post)) { echo 'success!'; }

}

add_action('the_post', 'update_shares');
```

The function is called and I even get the "success", but there is no change in the database. I installed some plugin that lets you see the queries to the database, but the query is not send.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `get_the_ID()`?  That function is supposed to be used in the loop.  Are you calling it from within a loop?  If not, you may need another way of getting the post ID.

Comment: The output is the ID of the currently viewed post. I'm not really using it in a loop, but it outputs the ID correctly.

Comment: Are all three of the array items in your wp_posts database table?  I only see "ID" and "comment_count" in my db.  Do you have a "shares" column?

Comment: Yes, it's a column that I added to the table.